# using wildcard and 'like' to compare contents of two columns in pgSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, wildcard

i have columns in two separate tables that i'm using in a join and subsequent update. i want to be able to see if one column has all of its content captured in a second column.

for instance, here is a sample of contents from each column:

```
city_table1 | city_table2
Portsmouth    Portsmouth, New Hampshire, USA
```

i want to be able to have a where clause in a select statement that will match the two columns based on the contents in city_table1 (but i can't just do a left or right trim based on content variance), so i'm envisioning something like

```
where city_table1 like ('%' + city_table2 '%')
```

is my logic off here? should i referse the two fields in this where clause? i've tried this in postgres and got no results when i know it should work if i have the syntax right.

thank you!

Comment: Side note: It's a bit weird to name a *column* with `table` as infix...

Comment: SQL uses `||` to concatenate strings and so [does Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html)

Comment: oh i know - those are dummy names just for clarity

Answer (score 6):

Postgres uses `||` to concatenate strings.  So:

```
where city_table2 like ('%' || city_table1 || '%')
```

Also, you have the comparison backwards.  The *shorter* string is surrounded by the `'%'`.

And, this would be simpler with regular expressions:

```
where city_table2 ~ city_table1
```